# Can't understand what "First arguments makes this function a method of mapping(int16 => uint256)." means here

Tags: solidity, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

```
function nextInitializedTickWithinOneWord(
    mapping(int16 => uint256) storage self,
    int24 tick,
    int24 tickSpacing,
    bool lte
) internal view returns (int24 next, bool initialized) {
    int24 compressed = tick / tickSpacing;
    if (lte) {
    (int16 wordPos, uint8 bitPos) = position(compressed);
    uint256 mask = (1 << bitPos) - 1 + (1 << bitPos);
    uint256 masked = self[wordPos] & mask;
```

From [here](https://uniswapv3book.com/docs/milestone_2/tick-bitmap-index/#flipping-flags) for the mapping parameter it is said **First arguments makes this function a method of mapping(int16 => uint256).** One thing to note is: when calling this function nothing is passed as agrument. I could not understand how it works.Help me to understand this.

One more thing i did not understand is how the **masked** value is calculated. Help me on this too.

Comment: This would be ok question if you remove the second part about the masked value calculation, which has nothing to do with it. Please do try to follow the SO's guidelines, especially as you're asking so many questions.

Comment: I thought it would be better if ask 2 question related to same topic together rather than asking it on 2 different question.

Answer (score 0):

This function is used as operator for the type `mapping(int16 => uint256)`.

Basically in solidity you can attach functions to a type using a `Using A for B` syntax. The first argument of these function is special, and it's easier to understand looking at some examples.

So, in your case the code will have a library with some functions that all perform some operation on `mapping(int16 => uint256)`. This is type `B`, and will appear as the first argument in the functions:

```
library LibraryName {
    function nextInitializedTickWithinOneWord(
        mapping(int16 => uint256) storage self,
        int24 tick,
        int24 tickSpacing,
        bool lte
    ) internal view returns (int24 next, bool initialized) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The main contract has a variable `ticks` of this type. Importing the library and using the syntax `Using A for B`, we can perform all the functions like this:

```
using LibraryName for mapping(int16 => uint256);
mapping(int16 => uint256) public ticks;

ticks.nextInitializedTickWithinOneWord(
    _tick,
    _tickSpacing,
    _lte
);
```

which is equivalent of doing:

```
LibraryName.nextInitializedTickWithinOneWord(
    ticks,
    _tick,
    _tickSpacing,
    _lte
);
```

Check the [docs here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.19/contracts.html#using-for) for a other examples. A common one is `Using SafeERC20 for IERC20`, you have a function `function safeTransfer(IERC20 token, address to, uint256 amount)` that you call with `token.safeTransfer(to, amount)`. So the first argument of the function is written "outside" kinda.

Hope it's clear. I can't help with the second question, maybe you're asking the meaning of `<<` and `&`? If so, `1 << bitPos` is basically `2**bitPos`, and `&` is bitwise AND. In any case I agree it's better to ask it in a separate question.